# New design: inconsistent rendering by preview

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Attention Jin: The new design has introduced some rendering inconsistency between the preview and final post. In the beta what you saw in the preview was exactly what was rendered in the final post. However in the new design this is no longer true. It appears that some font sizes are different between the two, e.g. the font employed for bold faces, etc. For example see my [post here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7912/2k-mid-2k-choose-0-cdot-30-2k-choose-2-cdot-31-cdots/7927#7927), and compare the size of the "HINT" in the preview and posted form. This is quite annoying since I go to great effort to control the layout so that the syntax reflects the semantics and such inconsistencies complicate this process.

Comment: FYI: You could use `&nbsp;` (Shift+Alt+Space on Mac OS X if you're using it) to insert a significant space.

Comment: I'm looking into this now. thanks.

Comment: @Jin, @Kenny: I try to align similar elts of equations on different lines, to clarify proofs. Being multiline LaTeX interspersed with plain text, I can't use LaTeX arrays etc to control layout. So I mix and match text and LaTeX "padding" to get my alignment (e.g. the first two equations [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3149) used to be aligned perfectly in the beta). I realize that this will break if certain design choices change, but I don't know any other way to achieve such layouts. Jin: will the design remain constant once it stabilizes, at least as it might affect such?

Comment: @Bill: I'm talking about the 2 spaces after **HINT**. Anyway, you could use `\text{...}` to insert plain text, and use `$$...$$` to create a display equation (center-aligned).

Comment: @KennyTM: Yes, I know that. The reason that I use LaTeX is that the sizes have less chance of changing if the design changes and, also, in some cases it needs to be consistent with the whitespace sizing employed in LaTeX renderings. The problem with putting text into LaTeX is that it's no longer searchable.

Comment: @Bill: The search engine (server side) doesn't care about LaTeX. It is searchable even inside the LaTeX mark-up. Also, like a real LaTeX document, I believe it is better to focus on the semantics, not microformatting. Anyway, we're going off-topic. :)

Comment: @KennyTM: That's precisely what I'm trying to do - focus on the semantics. Namely to have the syntax reflect the semantics, e.g. to align equations so that substitutions are obvious, so that similar structure is apparent, etc.  As for searching inside LaTeX I'll have to double check. I thought it didn't work but perhaps my prior test cases were exceptions.

Comment: @jin: Is there any chance this will be fixed soon? I find it really, really annoying. So much so that I am refraining from answering many questions till it is fixed.

Answer (score 2):

I see; the preview is 14px and the final rendered post is 15px. We fixed this.

Comment: Thanks but, alas, the bug isn't completely fixed. It appears that there is still an inconsistency. Namely line breaking isn't consistent (perhaps the preview pane is narrower?) E.g. in [this post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3852/if-ab-i-then-ba-i/3875#3875) "chain" wraps to a new line in the preview but not in the final. It would be really nice if the were completely consistent so that the preview is truly WYSIWYG.

Comment: @Bill: Yes, that's because the previous area's width is 640px and the final post's width is 660px.

Comment: @bill Jin will normalize the widths; sorry about that!